# How to write script for Linux Mint 14

Tags: linux, bash

## What I want to do

Write a script to set the screen resolution (1600 x 900) in Linux Mint 14 OS. Mint OS is installed in VMware Workstation 9 on my laptop.

## What I did before

Open terminal and execute three commands one by one:

1. cvt 1600 900
2. xrandr --newmode  "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900
   903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
3. xrandr --addmode Virtual1 "1600x900_60.00"
4. xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode "1600x900_60.00"
5. succeeded

## What I tried so far

create a `.py` file with following contents:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# screen script

cvt 1600 900
xrandr --newmode  "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode Virtual1 "1600x900_60.00"
xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode "1600x900_60.00"
```

## What I get

Failure.

## Need help

Could anyone help? Is the .py file is a bash script?

Comment: So you want to write a bash script, and... you create a python file with python as the interpreter but the contents is a shell script? I'm scratching my head here, this doesn't make the slightest sense.

Comment: sry i am new about script. i want to write a script so that i don'd need to execute the commands each time i start up my OS, i am not sure if i could use python here.

Comment: You can use python, but then you need to, well, write python code. You can use bash, but then you need to write a bash script. If you ask the python interpreter to process bash script, it won't work. Same for the other way around. They're different languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is the .py file is a bash script?

Obviously, yes. You wrote a bash script but your shebang says it should interpret python. Two solutions. Either adjust your shebang to `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or write python code.

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env bash`  is this indicate where the interpreter is?